# How to integrate payment gateway in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, firstdata

I'm newbie to hybris.i want to integrate payment gateway called FirstData with Hybris. What is the procedure to do it. I have heard about cispayment addon, is that the way to do it.If so how to do it, Can someone guide me please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I read some document about CIS. CIS is protocol/process for payment providers. cispayment addon is abstract module for CIS. You need configure it, you can find details at https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8ac999a3866910149e8f9c46855b9ce7.html
I don't know FirstData support CIS. Also you don't need CIS if FirstData not support it. You need to modifie payment page and backend process for FirstData. You can get documentation from FirstData.